# cannot run ansible to AWS EC2 created by terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, terraform

I have EC2 created by terraform, and I can login the ec2 using:
ssh -vvvv -i /home/ec2-user/.ssh/mykey.pub ec2-user@XX.XX.XX.XX without password,(XX.XX.XX.XX) is the IP of the EC2 created by terraform.

but when I try to run ansible file in terraform when ec2 is created, ansible cannot run and error message is:

```
aws_instance.dev (local-exec): TASK [Gathering Facts] 
*********************************************************
The authenticity of host 'XX.XX.XX.XX (XX.XX.XX.XX)' can't be 
established.
...
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
aws_instance.dev: Still creating... (6m40s elapsed)
```

note the ansible yml is started after I manually force the terraform to sleep for 6m and at that time, the EC2 already started (I can login it myself, although it showed "aws_instance.dev: Still creating...") i.e.

```
resource "aws_instance" "dev" {
  ...
      provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "sleep 6m && ansible-playbook -i hosts myansible.yml"
  }
  ...
}
```

I run the terraform as ec2-user, I set ansible yml as:

```
  remote_user: ec2-user
  become_user: ec2-user
```

what is the reason the ansible cannot ssh to the EC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a message for you:

> The authenticity of host 'XX.XX.XX.XX (XX.XX.XX.XX)' can't be 
>   established.
>   ...
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Either execute `ssh-keyscan XX.XX.XX.XX` before executing `ansible-playbook`, or disable [host key checking](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#host-key-checking) in ansible.

Comment: I did it before not work. so I created a new key using: ssh-keygen, ssh-agent bash, ssh-add key, then host_key_checking = False in ansible config, this time, works!  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: host_key_checking = False